# Repeat a Field Value

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, sum, max

A data table I'm working in has multiple rows of costs for an item that need to be summed but, one of the values from another field needs to be repeated on that summed row.  For example:

```
+-------------+------+-------------+
| ITEM NUMBER | COST | OTHER VALUE |
+-------------+------+-------------+
|      1      |  10  |      -1     |
|      2      |   4  |      -1     |
|      1      |  -2  |     123     |
|      3      |   3  |      -1     |

And lots more...
```

The results should look like:

```
+-------------+------+-------------+
| ITEM NUMBER | COST | OTHER VALUE |
+-------------+------+-------------+
|      1      |   8  |     123     |
|      2      |   4  |      -1     |
|      3      |   3  |      -1     |
```

I could make a table of item numbers with, "Other values," greater than zero but, am wondering if there's a cooler way.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How do you choose `other_value` 123 against -1 for `item_number` 1? What if the are 4 records for `item_number` 1 with `other_value` =  -10, -1, 123, 456: which value would you pick?

Comment: Tables have _columns_, not fields.

Comment: There are only ever two entries for the item.  The positive, "other value," is the one that needs to be repeated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple aggregation should work for your use case:

```
select item_number, sum(cost) cost, max(other_value) other_value
from mytable
group by item_number
```